# Using comparator with multiple comparators

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compare, comparator

I can use all the simple comparators in this code for sorting just fine but not the `ComplexComparator`. I couldn't figure it out how to code to get it to work properly. Any suggestion / explanation would be appreciated.

This is my main program:

```
package pkgTest;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] students = new Student[6];
        students[0] = new Student("Pete", 1989, 3.6);
        students[1] = new Student("Tomas", 1989, 3.9);
        students[2] = new Student("Helen", 1990, 3.6);
        students[3] = new Student("Steve", 1991, 3.7);
        students[4] = new Student("Natalie", 1993, 3.7);
        students[5] = new Student("John", 1992, 4.0);

        NameComparator byName
                = new NameComparator();
        BirthDateComparator byBirthDate
                = new BirthDateComparator();
        AverageComparator byAverage
                = new AverageComparator();

        ComplexComparator complexSorting
                = new ComplexComparator(byName,
                        byAverage);

        System.out.println("===============");
        System.out.println("Before sorting:");
        System.out.println("===============");
        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student.getName()
                    + " // " + student.getBirthDate()
                    + " // " + student.getAverage());
        }

        Arrays.sort(students, complexSorting);

        System.out.println("==============");
        System.out.println("After sorting:");
        System.out.println("==============");
        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student.getName()
                    + " // " + student.getBirthDate()
                    + " // " + student.getAverage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the rest of the classes:

```
package pkgTest;

public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int birthDate;
    private double average;

    public Student(String name, int birthDate,
            double average) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.average = average;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getBirthDate() {
        return this.birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(int birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return this.average;
    }

    public void setAverage(double average) {
        this.average = average;
    }
}


package pkgTest;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class ComplexComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    public ComplexComparator(Comparator<Student> one,
            Comparator<Student> another) {
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Student one, Student another) {
        /*This is the part that
        I just couldn't figure
        it out to get it work.

        It has to work no matter
        which 2 of the 3 comparators
        I use to set the input
        parameters of ComplexComparator.

        I have to make it work by
        modifying only this part of
        the code.*/
    }
}


package pkgTest;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class AverageComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student one, Student another) {
        if (one.getAverage()
                < another.getAverage()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (one.getAverage()
                == another.getAverage()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return +1;
        }
    }
}

package pkgTest;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class BirthDateComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student one, Student another) {
        if (one.getBirthDate()
                < another.getBirthDate()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (one.getBirthDate()
                == another.getBirthDate()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return +1;
        }
    }
}


package pkgTest;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student one, Student another) {
        return one.getName().
                compareToIgnoreCase(another.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to modify other parts of the code. It really doesn't make sense any other way.

Comment: Shouldn't you implement a complex comparison (like: if names are the same, then compare birthdays and if those are equal then compare the average) instead of using other `Comparator`s there?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not up to me, it's a task that has to be done in this way. Otherwise I wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel, but anyway. Your complex comparator should loop through the comparators and calls them one after another. As soon as one comparison is not 0, return its result. Otherwise go to the next. Note that Integer and Double have a compare() method.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, but even then he has to store the comparators which would have to be done outside of the `compare` method's code he claims is the only place he's allowed to edit.

Comment: @daniu sure, but he should probably know that, since he passes them in the constructor: `new ComplexComparator(byName, byAverage)`

Comment: My problem is once I passed them as parameters I don't know how to get their returned values from inside ComplexComparator.

Comment: @sasieightynine you store the comparators, using a field. If you don't know what fields are and what a constructor is yet, then take a huge step back, and learn these basics. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to modify the class `ComplexComparator` like the following, at least...

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ComplexComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    private Comparator<Student> comparatorOne;
    private Comparator<Student> comparatorTwo;

    public ComplexComparator(Comparator<Student> one,
            Comparator<Student> another) {
        this.comparatorOne = one;
        this.comparatorTwo = another;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Student one, Student another) {
        // make a first comparison using comparator one
        int comparisonByOne = comparatorOne.compare(one, another);

        // check if it was 0 (items equal in that attribute)
        if (comparisonByOne == 0) {
            // if yes, return the result of the next comparison
            return comparatorTwo.compare(one, another);
        } else {
            // otherwise return the result of the first comparison
            return comparisonByOne;
        }
    }
}
```

For more than two `Comparator`s you will need a `List` of them (or another overloaded constructor) and a loop that keeps a certain order of comparisons.

**EDIT**

For your additional requirement regarding sorting orders, this may be helpful:

```
    public class ComplexComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    private Comparator<Student> comparatorOne;
    private Comparator<Student> comparatorTwo;
    private boolean orderOneAscending = true;
    private boolean orderTwoAscending = true;

    /**
     * Constructor without any sort orders
     * @param one   a comparator
     * @param another   another comparator
     */
    public ComplexComparator(Comparator<Student> one, Comparator<Student> another) {
        this.comparatorOne = one;
        this.comparatorTwo = another;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that provides the possibility of setting sort orders 
     * @param one   a comparator
     * @param orderOneAscending sort order for comparator one 
     *      (true = ascending, false = descending)
     * @param another   another comparator
     * @param orderTwoAscending sort order for comparator two
     *      (true = ascending, false = descending)
     */
    public ComplexComparator(Comparator<Student> one, boolean orderOneAscending,
            Comparator<Student> another, boolean orderTwoAscending) {
        this.comparatorOne = one;
        this.comparatorTwo = another;
        this.orderOneAscending = orderOneAscending;
        this.orderTwoAscending = orderTwoAscending;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Student one, Student another) {
        int comparisonByOne;
        int comparisonByAnother;

        if (orderOneAscending) {
            /*  note that your lexicographical comparison in NameComparator 
                returns a negative integer if the String is greater!
                If you take two numerical Comparators, the order will
                turn into the opposite direction! */
            comparisonByOne = comparatorOne.compare(another, one);
        } else {
            comparisonByOne = comparatorOne.compare(one, another);
        }

        if (orderTwoAscending) {
            comparisonByAnother = comparatorTwo.compare(one, another);
        } else {
            comparisonByAnother = comparatorTwo.compare(another, one);
        }

        if (comparisonByOne == 0) {
            return comparisonByAnother;
        } else {
            return comparisonByOne;
        }
    }
}
```

Just play around with the values and try some modifications to get familiar with common problems concerning comparing and sorting.
I hope this will be helpful...

Comment: It works! Is it possible to add two more boolean type input parameters for each of the Comparators for being able to set the type of the sorting to ascending or descending?

Comment: What do you mean by "`boolean` type input parameters"? You could just change the order of the `Comparator`s when you call the constructor `ComplexComparator(Comparator<Student> one, Comparator<Student> another)`.

Comment: `public ComplexComparator(Comparator<Student> one,
            boolean ascending1,
            Comparator<Student> another,
            boolean ascending2) {
        this.one = .....}`

Comment: If I would run the sorting with one switch set to true and the other one set to false then It would produce one of the sortings ascending while the other one descending. For instance names by ascending while averages by descending. And I would be able to switch between ascending and descending sorting whether I change the input boolean parameters.

Comment: So basically add two more variables to the class with boolean types and rewrite the compare method to also check the boolean values when returning a value. Is it possible?

Comment: That is not possible by overriding the compare method! You will have to add another method and call it before the comparison or provide another constructor.

Comment: That will need an overloaded constructor... Will take me some time, but I try to provide something helpful soon.

Comment: Please check this out what do you think. https://codeshare.io/5XvnQY
It seems working fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177497/discussion-between-dehaar-and-sasieightynine).

Answer (score 3):

Modify Your ComplexComparator as below

```
public class ComplexComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

private List<Comparator<Student>> listComparators;

     @SafeVarargs
    public ComplexComparator(Comparator<Student>... comparators) {
        this.listComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Student studen1, Student studen2) {
        for (Comparator<Student> comparator : listComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(studen1, studen2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic complex comparator you can use for any type of of objects (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706899/1870795)):

```
public class ComplexComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private List<Comparator<T>> listComparators;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ComplexComparator(Comparator<T>... comparators) {
        listComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        for (Comparator<T> comparator : listComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

There will be an unchecked cast warning when you use it, but you can suppress that, given that it will cast successfully as long as your class is comparable.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Comparator<MyClass> comparator = new ComplexComparator(
        MyClass.ComparatorA,
        MyClass.ComparatorB);

Collections.sort(mySet, comparator);
```

If anyone knows a way how to not get that warning, please comment and I update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly how you want the solution to be presented. But from my understanding, if you want to do it by just putting code in the commented place, you can just try putting code like this.

Assuming the case when after comparing name, if same, you intend to move to average.

```
public int compare(Student StOne, Student StAnother) {
     if(one.compare(Sone, Sanother)==0) {
         return another.compare(StOne, StAnother);
         }
     else 
         return one.compare(StOne, StAnother);
     }
```

But for this, you need to ensure that the values you take in the constructor of ComplexComparator (byName, byAverage) should be the instance variables of the class, and need to be initialized in the constructor.

> ```
> public class ComplexComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
>
>  private Comparator<Student> one; 
>  private Comparator<Student> another;
>  public ComplexComparator(Comparator<Student> one,
>         Comparator<Student> another) {
>      this.one=one;
>      this.another=another;
> }
>
> @Override
> public int compare(Student one, Student another) {
>     //code given above
> } }
> ```

Comment: I cannot compile this, return value is missing. Also cannot find symbol, method compare(Student,Student)

Comment: try using this: public int compare(Student StOne, Student StAnother) {
     if(one.compare(Sone, Sanother)==0) {
         return another.compare(StOne, StAnother);
         }else return one.compare(StOne, StAnother);
     }

Comment: @sasieightynine check the edited code now. It will work fine now.